# Can someone explain the difference between these two http calls and why one fails but the other doesn't?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, rest, http, cors

So I inherited an app at work and am running into a bit of code I don't fully understand.

The app consists of a server-side API and a client-side single page app that calls into it. There is an account service in Angular that calls into the API to login. The API sets an auth cookie for the API's domain and we're all set to make authenticated API requests going forward.

The bit I don't understand is why the previous owners of the project had to urlencode the data going to the API and include an `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` value for the `Content-Type` header.

```
var qs = require('qs');
var user = { username: 'someUser', password: 'somePassword' };
$http.post(`${API_URL}/login`, qs.stringify(user), {
  headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' }
});
```

This request is then redirected from `API_URL/login` to `API_URL/account` which returns the now logged in account object to the app. All works fine with the code above, I just don't fully understand why the url encoding of the data is necessary. If I remove the `Content-Type` header and don't url encode the data, then I get the following CORS error (The API server runs locally at localhost:5000 and the client app runs locally at localhost:3000. CORS is enabled on the server to allow cross-origin requests from localhost:3000):

> XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://localhost:5000/login. The request was redirected to 'http://localhost:5000/account', which is disallowed for cross-origin requests that require preflight.

```
var user = { username: 'someUser', password: 'somePassword' };
$http.post(`${API_URL}/login`, user);
```

Can anyone explain what's going on here? It's not like URL encoding the data is changing the fact that the request gets redirected, yet it succeeds and responds as expected in the first case but throws that CORS error in the second case.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The server is set up to only accept URL encoded form data. When you remove that header, you are posting a raw JSON body, which the server doesn't quite understand. It looks like the request is being redirected to an accounts route which does not accept HTTP requests outside of its own domain origin.  You should see the same error if you send the header

```
Content-Type: application/json
```

Comment: I believe that's the header it defaults to when I don't include one. I'm still a bit confused though because there are other methods in the account service that POST without url encoding and they seem to work fine. `$http.post(\`${API_URL}/cashout\`, { userId: userId })`. That one appears to work fine and they did not url encode the data or change the content type header.

Comment: It's a server side issue. The server expects a Web form when URL encoded data is required, but cash out is designed as Rest API for cross origin calls. Do you have documentation on the server API

Comment: Yeah I control the server. I run both apps locally. The API is setup using Swagger. I'll do some more digging. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Happy to look at the swagger doc if you post it in the answer

Comment: Sure, if you're up to it :) https://gist.github.com/chevex/d768b23592bd102ba298303aff4a77c5

Comment: The `/login` endpoint is actually handled by a user library we use internally. It's a company npm module we configure in our apps. Here is the code for configuring it. Let me also find the actual code in the user lib that handles the login request. https://gist.github.com/chevex/67ef6d4e309395eb8ca96fb7ad7cf440

Comment: Here is the internal code of the user library where the login express handler is configured. Maybe the issue is that it's redirecting from here to the swagger API? https://gist.github.com/chevex/cb8704c7f4940cfda2b27c22e9f3086e

Comment: It's a lot to sift through so don't kill yourself over it. You got me on the right track either way and I'm sure I'll figure it out eventually.

Comment: My guess is that the users.middleware in this link https://gist.github.com/chevex/67ef6d4e309395eb8ca96fb7ad7cf440 is where the problem exists